# Can I add job to queue without start worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I trying to use `resque` and I have a next question - if I have a job class with this methods

```
class Foo
  @queue = :foobar
  class << self
    def async_execute!(foobar_id, str)
      Resque.enqueue(Foo, foobar_id, str)
    end

    def perform(foobar_id, str)
      puts "Hello to #{str} from #{foobar_id}" 
    end
  end
end
```

but I do not want that workers would run and execute this job, I want simple add this job to queue and manually start worker with rake task.How I can do that?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Why not just add it when you want it to run?

Comment: @Oleander mm, what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of adding it now and running it later, why not just add it later when it needs to be executed?

Comment: @Oleander Oh, good idea :) Thank you, but it is not my case